# Flutter: Which In App Purchases Service should I use?

Tags: flutter

Which IAP service should I use for a flutter app that sells **non consumable products** (one time payment products)?

I've looked around, and all I could find was people promoting RevenueCat, and their opinions sound more like ads than anything else.

So I'd like to hear your opinions:

Should I create my own backend to handle transactions or go for a 3rd party option (which would cost me about **%1** of my revenue [doesn't sound like much, but when you think about it, their pricing doesn't really make that much sense?])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried RevenueCat, but a few years ago, in my own Flutter app I've used the [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package + Firebase Cloud Functions ([firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) and [firebase_functions](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions) packages) to implement in-app purchases of non-consumable products.

This approach is indeed pretty complicated, especially for the first-timer. In this case, you'll also need some JavaScript/TypeScript skills because those are the languages FB functions are written with. In the end, your functions will be interacting with [Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher).

You'd better google some up-to-date tutorials on the topic, but here is a draft plan:

1. Setup and connect your project to Firebase using Firebase CLI.
2. Install the required Flutter packages and read their docs carefully.
3. Create a `functions` folder in your project's root and install the NPM dependencies ("firebase-admin", "firebase-functions", "googleapis", etc.).
4. Write your functions in the `src/index.ts` file
5. Deploy the functions to your Firebase account.
6. Call the functions in your app's code as needed.

Here is how a typical IAP-related FB function in `index.ts` looks like:

```
export const loadProducts = functions
  .region('europe-west1', 'us-central1')
  .https.onCall(async (data) => {
    const packageName: string = data.packageName;

    try {
      await authClient.authorize();
      const res = await playDeveloperApiClient.inappproducts.list({
        packageName: packageName,
      });
      const activeProducts = res.data.inappproduct?.filter(
        (product) => product.status == 'active'
      );

      if (res.status === 200) {
        return {
          data: activeProducts,
          status: 200,
          message: 'Product list fetch successful!',
        };
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('CloudFunction error: ', error);
    }

    return {
      status: 500,
      message: 'Failed to fetch product list. Try again!',
    };
  });
```

and here is how you call it from your app:

```
final packageName = appInfo.packageName;
      final httpsCallable = fbFunctions.httpsCallable('loadProducts');

      httpsCallable.call({'packageName': packageName}).then(
        (rawResult) async {
          final resultMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(rawResult.data as Map);
          final result = FbFunctionResult.fromJson(resultMap);
          final isProductListFetched = result.status == 200;

          if (isProductListFetched && result.data != null) {
            final productList = result.data! as List<dynamic>;
            // ignore: avoid_dynamic_calls
            final productIdsSet = productList.map((e) => e['sku'] as String).toSet();
            final productDetailsList = await loadProducts(productIdsSet);

            if (isMounted() && productDetailsList != null) {
              products.value = productDetailsList;
            }
          }
        },
      );
```

This works, but this does take effort and courage. So if there are time constraints and you just need to get the job done, it's probably better to opt for a third-party service. Otherwise, take a chance to learn more about Google Play APIs and inner workings of IAPs.

Here is a [good article](https://medium.com/@msasikanth/google-play-iap-verification-using-cloud-functions-bd8c3a22f9b9) even if outdated.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! I decided to be brave and implement my own backend using this up to date tutorial using Firebase https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0, I'm still new to Flutter, but I think with this approach I'll learn a lot more about Firebase and api's which I'm going to need anyway :)

Comment: Great! You certainly will :) I needed just 3 pretty simple functions in my "index.ts" for the same purpose as yours. Learning Firebase and the docs actually takes more time and effort than writing code.